# How to map bar memory address to user mode virtual address on Linux?

Tags: linux, dictionary, memory

I want to map bar memory address(physical address) to user mode virtual address. currently, I can use mmap API to implement this function.
eg. on application, call mmap API, and in driver's .mmap callback function, we can call dma_mmap_coherent API to map physical memory to user mode virtual address.

But, I want to map any physical memory which I allocated in driver to virtual address. I want to call dma_mmap_coherent function, but it need "vm_area_struct *vma" as input parameter. How did I prepare "vm_area_struct *vma" parameter? (I don't want to use mmap API to map physical memory to virtual memory).
eg: there is one physical memory in driver which named B, I want to call ioctl in application and then driver map B to virtual address in ioctl callback.

1. I try to allocate "vm_area_struct *vma" in driver, but it doesn't work. because "vma" is used to descript the user mode virtual address.
2. I try the dma S/G map. Application has virtual memory A, and call sg_alloc_table in driver, and then map the memory to virtual memory, it can works. but I don't know how to map the specified physical memory.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.